# How to know that xdmp:document-insert function has finished insertion in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I would like to know about [`xdmp:document-insert`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-insert) function in Marklogic. A callback or finished event? This kind of information is not available in the official documentation.

How can I get the event that `xdmp:document-insert` is finished his task in Marklogic 8?

Answer (score 3):

When the call returns, the document has been inserted.

Answer (score 1):

A document is fully inserted when the transaction during which is was inserted finishes committing. That means that if you do something like this:

```
xdmp:document-insert($uri, $content),

fn:doc($uri)
```

(which values for $uri and $content, of course), you're not going to see the document. Why? Because these two statements are part of the same transaction, which hasn't completed when you call fn:doc().

If you're wondering when your middle tier will know when MarkLogic has finished a document insert, that will be when the call returns (unless you're doing a multi-statement transaction, in which case it will finish when you tell it to commit).

For more detail, I encourage you to read the [Understanding Transactions in MarkLogic Server](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#chapter) chapter of the Application Developer's Guide. After that, if you have a more specific question about what you're trying to accomplish, let us know.